# Laravel 5 replace [string] with (php) code / include

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

In my days before Laravel (5) I had a system which replaced a placeholder with a PHP script with the same name as the placeholder. These 'plugins' were meant to add functionality simply by adding a plugin code in the text (edited with my own CMS).

**Let me give you an example:**

The user maintains a page in the CMS. On every page can select multiple images in the 'gallery' field for that page. These are not added to the text, the images field is separate from the content. This text fields contains an array (json object) with the images after saving.

If he wants to use the images in the webpage he has to add a 'plugin' to show the images by adding [gallery] in the text at the position he desires.

When the page is shown [gallery] is replaced with a PHP script (gallery.plugin.php) which takes the array of images and shows them nicely formatted and configured with a lightbox gallery script to view them in a bigger size.

Users don't have to worry about the layout and functionality of the gallery and can put them anywhere in the content they like.

**The way I did it the old way:**
(Old, never updated code, worked flawlessly)

```
public function decorateContent($content)
{
    if ($_parts = preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $content, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))
    {
        foreach ($_parts as $key => $value)
        {
            if (strstr($value, "[") and strstr($value, "]"))
            {
                $_plugin = explode(":", str_replace(array("[", "]"), "", $value));
                if (file_exists("templates/plugins/" . str_replace("_", "/", trim($_plugin[0])) . ".plugin.php"))
                {
                    $cntnt .= $this->get_include_content("templates/plugins/" . str_replace("_", "/", trim($_plugin[0])) . ".plugin.php", $_plugin);
                }

            }
            else
                $cntnt .= trim($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $cntnt = trim($cntnt);
    }
    return $cntnt;
}



function get_include_content($filename, $_plugin)
{
    global $db, $Website, $parameter;

    if (is_file($filename))
    {
        ob_start();
        include($filename);
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this I easily could add all functionality I wanted, [gallery], [form_contact] (_ translates to a slash for the path: form/contact.php) etc. Just create a script in the plugin directory with the same name as the plugin placeholder in the text.

Besides underscore's for path translation some plugins can be fed with variables by using : in the plugin name, ex. [intro:3] In this example 3 is the amount of introblocks (div's with content) that are shown in this particular script.

**Where to start in Laravel 5**

I would like to add this functionality again in my Laravel 5 projects but I like to do it the right way this time. Are there any preferred ways to do this decently?

Comment: this question is too localized in my opinion.

Comment: "Are there any preferred ways to do this decently?" would put your question closed / on hold

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is related to a template or view should use blade templates/partials. You can pull the template from wherever your want db/file.

Before rendering the view, during the build process, you should pick up the template that has the functionality inside and/or send params to it, in your example your images array, then replace your own syntax in the CMS post/page content or whatever with the blade include syntax. Finally, Blade will parse the whole template with the plugin added.

If you have a good architecture, you should be able to add the specific js/css to the main template as well as the fragment you need and require those assets into any template.

I think your question is a big one, because it's not just about a function, it's about architecture and functionality, in other words, implementation, and that is how you plan things and what issues you face during the build process.

Hope this helps :)